# ViewState variables not sticking around

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to keep track of some values, which are incremented with new records from a database.  The values are not sticking around when the page reloads though.

This is the property I am trying it with (just a count of all of the records I retrieve):

```
public int last
{
    get 
    { 
        if (ViewState["last"] != null) 
            return (int)ViewState["last"]; 
        return 0;
    }
    set 
    { 
        ViewState["last"] = value; }
    }
```

And I am trying to display it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string output = "Last Time: " + last + ", this time: " + DbData.Count;
    last = DbData.Count;
    Response.Write(output);
}
```

Unfortunately, the  output every time is something like: `Last Time: 0, this time: 232253`.

I have this site running on `IIS`, and I have checked to make sure that the View State was enabled:

[image: Pages and Controls]

---

I don't know what else to try, can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: I think you need change (string output) and  (last = DbData.Count;) line order (last = DbData.Count;) before (string output) after

Comment: The first time i use `last` I am using the value which should've been set last time, then in the next line I update it.  Even if these lines were backwards I would still be seeing something other than a `0` in my output.

Comment: How are you reloading the page?

Comment: I am using `FusionCharts` to to build charts, and there is a `refreshInterval` which makes a call to this code every `x` seconds.  And everytime this happens I would like to provide an incremented value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `FusionCharts`. However, ViewState lives only for the current page's lifecycle.

You might want to try SessionState which persist data between pages.

```
public int last
{
    get 
    { 
        if (Session["last"] != null) 
            return (int)Session["last"]; 
        return 0;
    }
    set { Session["last"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: This works.  Is the only difference between `Session` and `ViewState` variables their lifecycles?

Comment: On initial page load, ViewState is always null. On the other hand, SessionState maintains the previously saved data. ***I guess*** in your case FusionCharts requests information as a new page (instead of post back), as the result ViewState is 0. You can read more [here](http://devshop.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-sessionstate-cookies-and-cache/)